# wwwありなしを、htaccessで統一したいです。正しい記述か確認させてください。

Tags: .htaccess

wwwありなしを、htaccessで統一したいです。
下記で正しいでしょうか？

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.就\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://就.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

間違えると大変なので、念のために確認させてください。

Comment: 確認するだけでしたら、https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/　このようなサイトも利用してみてください

Comment: こちらはアップロードしたからチェックする物ではないですか？間違った状態でアップロードはできないので、詳しい方に確認してもらいたいです。

Comment: 確認できますよ。 
https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=734c11d5-088f-535e-95bf-01612fe757c2

Comment: @nicomesecond 先のコメントのリンクは記述チェッカーなので、[こんなかんじ](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=db25f93e-4ccb-5886-80b4-4ad58557a4f3)でチェックできますよ。301のまえに302で一旦仮アップした方がいいとは思いますけど、ありなしを統一するのは”無し”のほうに統一するんですかね？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

www無しに統一したいのであれば質問に記述の通りで問題ないかと思います。
ホスト名以外の配下ディレクトリも引き継がれるので、
どういったURLを想定しているか分かりませんがwwwはすべて削除されるかと思います。

また、www無しの場合はルールから外れるので置換されません。
コメントにある[オンラインチェッカー(htaccess tester)](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)ですが、
チェッカーにご自身で想定URLを打ち込んで確認した方が確実かと思いますよ。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

**追記**

赤字で表示されている内容はエラーではなく以下の意味で表示されています。
`This rule was not met.`
（この条件を満たしていない。）

Comment: アップロードして確認してみましたが、真っ白な画面しか出てきません。

Comment: リダイレクトされブラウザに表示されているURLは変更されていますか？されているのであればhtaccessの記述とは別の問題です。そもそもリダイレクトしたURLではなくwww無しのURLには接続できますか？あとはマルチバイトが利用されているURLなので、文字コードなどの設定とかでしょうか？このhtaccessの文字コードはなんですか？

Comment: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: 上記がチェック結果です。

Comment: 恐縮です上記のアドレスです。

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.就\.com$ This rule was not met.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://就.com/$1 [R=301,L] This rule was not met.このメッセージはエラーですよね？

Comment: ちゃんと認識しているかサーチコンソールなどで確認できないのでしょうか？

Comment: そこが原因でしたか訂正してみます。恐縮ですが、ドメイン名を削除いただいてもいいでしょうか？そのドメイン先に迷惑になると困るので。

Comment: 消しておきました。念のため、コメントを再投稿しておきます。期待する動作が分からないのですが、3行目のRewriteCondのルールでホスト名がwww.就.comではないのでRewriteRuleが実行されないという状態です。記述通り正しく動いていると思いますが、想定外なのでしょうか？エラーではなく、このルールに引っかかり、ここでRewriteの実行を止めたという表示です。もし、困っているようでしたら20分後ならチャットルームを作成できるのでそちらで聞きましょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。根本的に間違っているのなら、そのようにお願いします。コピペした情報なので、正直わかっていません、コピペ元に問題があるのですね。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97228/discussion-between-sieg-and-nicomesecond)しましょう。